# Control the events of current/active app in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, controls

I am new in XCode and iOS.
Is there any way to control the current active app. For instance if the  pdf viewer is the current active app then I would like to navigate through the pages or if the  photo viewer is the active app, I would like to navigate through the images in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode when you programming to make an app you only have control to of your app not of the others apps in your iPhone so I think the answer for your question is no you cant control photo viewer unless you are just using it to select an image of your apps usage.

Comment: But I am able to change ipod music player by [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] skipToNextItem];